# Read multiple sub configurations from web.config

Tags: c#, configuration

I have these tags in a simple web.config

```
      <Data>
        <format type="F1">
          <Child1>
            Apples
          </Child1>
          <Child2>
            Pears
          </Child2>
        </format>
        <format type="F2">
          <Child3>
            Oranges
          </Child3>
        </format>
      </Data>
```

As you can see I use multiple format tags identified by an attribute. Every format has its own children.

In my code I need easy access to these config. But I'm not sure how.
The Web.config can be changed if needed. I need something like this:

```
mySetting.Format["F1"].["Child1"]
```

It is just for reading the settings. Nothing is written.

I've been reading all morning about the configuration API and I know how to use it with simple (non-duplicate) tags. I've also looked at the *ConfigurationCollection* but didn't got that to work either.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

After Narek his remarks I changed my approach.
I'm now using a web.config like this:

```
<Data>
  <F1 
    Child1="Apples" 
    Child2="Pears"
    />
  <F2 Child3="Oranges" />
</Data>
```

My settings class is now:

```
public class Settings : ConfigurationSection
{
    // Create a "Format" element.
    [ConfigurationProperty("F1")]
    public Format1Element Format1
    {
        get
        {
            return (Format1Element )this["F1"];
        }
        set
        { this["F1"] = value; }
    }

    // Create a "Format" element.
    [ConfigurationProperty("F2")]
    public Format2Element Format2
    {
        get
        {
            return (Format2Element )this["F2"];
        }
        set
        { this["F2"] = value; }
    }
}

public class Format1Element : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("Child1", IsRequired = true)]
    public String Child1
    {
        get
        {
            return (String)this["Child1"];
        }
        set
        {
            this["Child1"] = value;
        }
    }
}

public class Format2Element : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("Child3", IsRequired = true)]
    public String Child3
    {
        get
        {
            return (String)this["Child3"];
        }
        set
        {
            this["Child3"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I can now get my settings using:

```
settings.Format1.Child1;
```

I used this page as reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2tw134k3(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function

```
public static string GetChild(string formatType, string child)
    {
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(filePath))
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(reader);

            var val = doc.Descendants().Where(a => a.Name.LocalName == "format" && a.FirstAttribute.Value == formatType).Select(a => a.Element(child)).First().Value;
            return val;
        }            

    }
```

Call

```
 GetChild("F1", "Child1");
```

Otherwise you can do it in this way

```
    <configuration> 
     ...
      <appSettings>
        <add key ="[F1_Child1]" value="Apples"/> 
        <add key ="[F1_Child2]" value="Pears"/> 
      </appSettings>
    </configuration>
```

and get your child

```
  var child =  ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings [ "F1_Child1" ] ;
```

Comment: Thanks. I'd hoped to avoid using a XMLReader. Can't this be done with the standard Configuration API?

Comment: I just edited my answer. Look at that. But in this case you must change the format of your data

Comment: @PaulMeems Why do you don't want to use XmlReader?

Comment: I'm also reading other settings in other parts of my application using the Configuration API. But I can use XmlReader it is just a matter of taste ;)
In the near future other formats might also need settings and perhaps another developer will continue my work. For readability I prefer the most simple solution ;)

Comment: If your solution were simple, it were been easy to implement ;)

Comment: I've just updated my question with a solution that works for me.